# boost math special functions compilation error when using boost for TR1

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I have been upgrading an already working project that depends on boost 1.43 to boost 1.52. When compiling, I receive a strange set of errors in the math special functions headers. Unfortunately, I am unable to pin point the code that is causing it from the output below. The math errors seem to pop out of nowhere as `DisplayWindow.h` and `DisplayWindow.cpp` do not use these math functions. The compiler is gcc 4.1.2 on Linux. The same occurs on boost 1.51. Does anyone know what might be causing the problem?

I am not sure if it matters -- I am using boost as a TR1 drop-in described over [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/usage.html#boost_tr1.usage.include_style).

```
In file included from /home/p/plau/include/boost/fusion/tuple/tuple.hpp:22,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/fusion/tuple.hpp:10,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/fusion/include/tuple.hpp:10,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:58,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/tr1/utility.hpp:117,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/tr1/tr1/utility:38,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/serialization/nvp.hpp:19,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/bimap/bimap.hpp:57,
             from /home/p/plau/include/boost/bimap.hpp:13,
             from /home/p/plau/include/rlearn/Action.h:13,
             from /home/p/plau/include/rlearn/EnvWrapper.h:5,
             from ./rlsiva/DisplayWindow.h:9,
             from src/DisplayWindow.cpp:1:
/home/p/plau/include/boost/fusion/tuple/detail/preprocessed/tuple.hpp:21:7: warning: no newline at end of file
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function T boost::math::trunc(const T&, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:24: error: raise_rounding_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function int boost::math::itrunc(const T&, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:47: error: raise_rounding_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function long int boost::math::ltrunc(const T&, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:62: error: raise_rounding_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function boost::long_long_type boost::math::lltrunc(const T&, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:79: error: raise_rounding_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<0>&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:82: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:82: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:85: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:85: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:103: error: check_series_iterations is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:103: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<53>&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:115: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:115: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:118: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:118: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<64>&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:168: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:168: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:171: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:171: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<24>&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:223: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:223: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:226: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:226: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T, float, float, float, float, float>::type boost::math::log1p(T, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:320: error: checked_narrowing_cast is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:320: error: expected primary-expression before , token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:320: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function float boost::math::log1p(float, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355: error: expected primary-expression before float
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355: error: expected ; before float
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355: error: expected unqualified-id before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358: error: expected primary-expression before float
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358: error: expected ; before float
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358: error: expected unqualified-id before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function long double boost::math::log1p(long double, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367: error: expected primary-expression before long
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367: error: expected ; before long
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367: error: expected unqualified-id before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370: error: expected primary-expression before long
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370: error: expected ; before long
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370: error: expected unqualified-id before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function double boost::math::log1p(double, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392: error: expected primary-expression before double
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392: error: expected ; before double
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392: error: expected unqualified-id before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395: error: expected primary-expression before double
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395: error: expected ; before double
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395: error: expected unqualified-id before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T, float, float, float, float, float>::type boost::math::log1pmx(T, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:465: error: raise_domain_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:465: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:468: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:468: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:487: error: check_series_iterations is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:487: error: expected primary-expression before > token
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/hypot.hpp: In function T boost::math::detail::hypot_imp(T, T, const Policy&):
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/hypot.hpp:45: error: raise_overflow_error is not a member of boost::math::policies
/home/p/plau/include/boost/math/special_functions/hypot.hpp:45: error: expected primary-expression before > token
make: *** [../../objs/rlsiva/release/DisplayWindow.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/p/plau/retina/project/components/rlsiva'
```

UPDATE: Trying to compile the same code on Windows with mingw-gcc 4.7 and boost 1.52 gives the following output.

```
In file included from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/constants/calculate_constants.hpp:11:0,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp:288,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/complex/details.hpp:22,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/complex/asin.hpp:9,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/complex.hpp:10,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/tr1/complex.hpp:13,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/tr1/tr1/complex:28,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:15,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:32,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy.hpp:14,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp:17,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/airy.hpp:10,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions.hpp:15,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/random/generate_canonical.hpp:22,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/random.hpp:52,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Random.h:4,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Comparators.h:4,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/function/StoredActionFunction.h:5,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/ValueFunction.h:18,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Extractor.h:8,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/DataStructures.h:7,
                 from ./rlsiva/SivaController.h:5,
                 from src/DisplayWindow.cpp:3:
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function 'T boost::math::trunc(const T&, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:24:14: error: 'raise_rounding_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function 'int boost::math::itrunc(const T&, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:47:31: error: 'raise_rounding_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function 'long int boost::math::ltrunc(const T&, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:62:32: error: 'raise_rounding_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp: In function 'boost::long_long_type boost::math::lltrunc(const T&, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/trunc.hpp:79:49: error: 'raise_rounding_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
In file included from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/complex/asin.hpp:12:0,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/complex.hpp:10,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/tr1/complex.hpp:13,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/tr1/tr1/complex:28,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:15,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:32,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy.hpp:14,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp:17,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/airy.hpp:10,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions.hpp:15,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/random/generate_canonical.hpp:22,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/random.hpp:52,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Random.h:4,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Comparators.h:4,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/function/StoredActionFunction.h:5,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/ValueFunction.h:18,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Extractor.h:8,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/DataStructures.h:7,
                 from ./rlsiva/SivaController.h:5,
                 from src/DisplayWindow.cpp:3:
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<0>&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:82:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:82:44: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:85:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:85:47: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:103:4: error: 'check_series_iterations' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:103:39: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<53>&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:115:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:115:44: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:118:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:118:47: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<64>&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:168:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:168:44: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:171:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:171:47: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'T boost::math::detail::log1p_imp(const T&, const Policy&, const mpl_::int_<24>&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:223:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:223:44: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:226:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:226:47: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT>::type boost::math::log1p(T, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:320:11: error: 'checked_narrowing_cast' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:320:55: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:320:74: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'float boost::math::log1p(float, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355:43: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355:43: error: expected ';' before 'float'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:355:48: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358:46: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358:46: error: expected ';' before 'float'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:358:51: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'long double boost::math::log1p(long double, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367:43: error: expected primary-expression before 'long'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367:43: error: expected ';' before 'long'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:367:54: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370:46: error: expected primary-expression before 'long'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370:46: error: expected ';' before 'long'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:370:57: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'double boost::math::log1p(double, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392:43: error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392:43: error: expected ';' before 'double'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:392:49: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395:46: error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395:46: error: expected ';' before 'double'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:395:52: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp: In function 'typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT>::type boost::math::log1pmx(T, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:465:14: error: 'raise_domain_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:465:44: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:468:15: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:468:47: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:487:4: error: 'check_series_iterations' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:487:39: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
In file included from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/complex/fabs.hpp:10:0,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/complex.hpp:28,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/tr1/complex.hpp:13,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/tr1/tr1/complex:28,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:15,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:32,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy.hpp:14,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp:17,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/airy.hpp:10,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions.hpp:15,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/random/generate_canonical.hpp:22,
                 from e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/random.hpp:52,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Random.h:4,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Comparators.h:4,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/function/StoredActionFunction.h:5,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/ValueFunction.h:18,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/Extractor.h:8,
                 from e:/games/rlearn/rlearn/DataStructures.h:7,
                 from ./rlsiva/SivaController.h:5,
                 from src/DisplayWindow.cpp:3:
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/hypot.hpp: In function 'T boost::math::detail::hypot_imp(T, T, const Policy&)':
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/hypot.hpp:45:14: error: 'raise_overflow_error' is not a member of 'boost::math::policies'
e:/code/boost_1_52_0/boost/math/special_functions/hypot.hpp:45:46: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
make: *** [../../objs/rlsiva/release/DisplayWindow.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/e/retina/project/components/rlsiva'
```

UPDATE2: Same code compiles fine on Windows with VC10 using VC's TR1 support.

Comment: This could be easily be caused by a missing semi-colon at the end of the definition of a class or a structure or by a missing paranthesis in your file.

Comment: I am upgrading an already working project. The program compiles fine with the previous boost 1.43, the only thing that changed is the boost library to 1.52

Comment: GCC 4.1.2 was released February 13, 2007. That's very old!

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use it. The manual says it has been tested on gcc 3.4 and later. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/main_overview/compilers_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I see the same types of error messages in our code, and can reproduce them with this example:

```
#include<boost/random.hpp>
#include<iostream>
int main(){
  boost::random::mt19937 ranGen(std::time(0));
  boost::uniform_int<> dist(1, 50);
  std::cout << dist(randGen) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

when compiling with the same TR1 drop-in method:

```
g++ tst.cpp -I/path/to/boost/include/boost/tr1/tr1 -I/path/to/boost/include
```

using boost 1.52.0 and gcc 4.4.6.

In our case, `boost/random.hpp` covers the functionality we need, but also includes other headers that ultimately leads to these strange compiler errors.

We were able to work around this by replacing

```
#include<boost/random.hpp>
```

with the more specific to our needs:

```
#include<boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include<boost/random/uniform_int.hpp>
#include<ctime>
```

thus leaving out the problematic headers.

You may be able to use the same kind of workaround for Your usage of `random.hpp` and `bimap.hpp`.